# Shortcut for Block Comment is not working

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, keymaps

it should be a very simple task but really I dont know how to solve this problem!

I use Pycharm and I have an Italian keyobard so no `/` on my keyboard (to do it I have to press `Shift + 7`), and the built in shortcut to comment a block of code in Pycharm is `Ctrl + /`. So I decided to create my own shortcut but nothing seems to work!

The strange thing is that I have tried to create my own shortcut for other commands, like for example `Run` or `Search everywhere` and with no problems I have inserted `Alt + R` or `Alt + X` and they all works perfectly!
The only command that doesnt accept my own shortcut is `Comment with Block Comment` (by the way, as you can see from the screenshoot below, I have tried the same combinations of `Search everywhere`: `Alt + X`, so its not a problem of the particulare keys that I have choosen).
I post a screenshot of my screen (the Keymap that I use is Windows, changing the Keymap to others like Eclipse or Emacs doesnt change the result).

If anyone had the same, or similar problem and can give me some help it would be very appreciate!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out that Block comments in python doesnt exists:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6185/Block-comments-in-python-files

But anyway I can achieve a similar result using `Comment with Line Comment`, I can attribute a shortcut to it and everything works perfectly!